# Why float is not considered as an integral type?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I'm watching over the `type_traits`, and accidentally came across the fact, that `float` is not considered to be an integral type. It was kinda surprise for me.

I looked through the web to find appropriate information, but couldn't find anything concerning that fact. All I could find is something like [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral):

> If T is an integral type (bool, char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, short, int, long, long long, including any signed, unsigned, and cv-qualified variants), provides the member constant value equal true. For any other type, value is false.

So the question here:
Why did the C++ Standards Committee decide that float is **not** an integral type?

Comment: There is no reason to close this question. It's a misinterpretation of 'integral', which can mean 'central' or 'constituent', and there will be other people in the future who think of that other meaning first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An integral type is one which has only integers - whole numbers. The purpose of floating point  types is to represent non-integers as well.

From the [Wikipedia page on integer (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29):

> In computer science, an integer is a datum of integral data type, a data type which represents some finite subset of the mathematical integers.

Comment: Jon Skeet is always the solution.

Comment: @nhahtdh: But it's not a finite subset of the mathematical integers. If `float` were considered an integral type, that would imply that 0.5 is considered an integer.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect your confusion is which meaning of *integral* applies:

> Definition of INTEGRAL
>
> 1 a : essential to completeness : constituent
>   "an integral part of the curriculum"
>
> b (1) : **being, containing, or
>   relating to one or more mathematical integers** (2) : relating to or
>   concerned with mathematical integration or the results of mathematical
>   integration

It's not (1a) essential to completeness (which `float` would be), but (1b) relating to the integers.

Answer (score 5):

Jon's answer is right, but here's a short overview of *some* [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) that might help you:

- `is_integral` checks if a type is integral type
- `is_floating_point` checks if a type is floating point type
- [`is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) checks if a type is either integral or floating point type

And [here](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/TypeHiearchy.pdf) is a nice graph from Howard Hinnant that shows the relationship between the type categories.

Answer (score -1):

Those are integral types because while storing integer types or characters in c++ ,it stores in integer format (even characters i.e., in ASCII format).But floats are not stored like that we don't have any method to convert floats to binary format

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Text only answers are usually not very useful unless they explain what they do. Please consider adding an explanation of what you changed or wrote or any reference.